# Ground connections and symbols in schematics: should they be separate or connected?

Tags: audio, ground, negative

I'm new to this world of electronics and I'm trying to make a fuzz face pedal. I'm not comfortable with the notion and symbol of ground connections. Do I have to connect all the ground points to the negative pole or just connect them separately?

[image: Schematics of the fuzz face pedal, from http://fuzzcentral.ssguitar.com/fuzzface.php]

Schematics of the fuzz [face pedal](http://fuzzcentral.ssguitar.com/fuzzface.php)

Comment: They can all be connected to the same point.  On a PCB (Printed Circuit Board), you will usually have a ground place or layer to make those connections.  So they will indeed be connected to the negative pole.  If you add a mixed-signals IC, the ground connections would be different.

Comment: Also, Not shown on schematic is the signals should be physically close to ground to reduce antenna effects to stay hum. Such as twisted paired wire, otherwise keep it tight and small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the ground symbols must be connected together.  The exact routing of the connections does not matter.

In the circuit you show, the negative terminal of the battery IS NOT connected to ground.  It is connected to the "ring" terminal of the input jack, and the sleeve of the jack is connected to ground.  This arreangement means that the circuit is turned on when a plug is inserted in the input jack, and automatically turned off when the plug is removed, so an actual power switch is not required.

Comment: Thank you so much! So in this different variation I would have to connect the ground to the negative pole, because there is a switch?
http://www.6v6power.ru/inf/Distortion/Fuzz%20Face%20(by%20Dallas%20Arbiter).jpg

Comment: No.  That circuit uses PNP transistors so the negative terminal of the battery is the power supply, and ground is on the positive side of the circuit (watch the +/- signs on the battery).  The input jack still acts as the power switch, and switch S1 lets you bypass the effect without having to re-patch your instrument cables.  They have used two different ground symbols in that circuit - they should still all be connected together.

Comment: I understand... And why on one input there are two triangle connections and in the other there is just one?

Comment: The input connector is a "Tip, Ring, Sleeve (TRS)" jack (sometimes called "stereo").  It has one contact for the tip of the plug (conected to the capacitor), one for the ring (connected to the battery), and one for the sleeve (body) of the connector.  The output is just a TS or "mono" jack, with contacts for the tip and sleeve.

Answer (score 0):

Every connection you make with the ground will automatically be on the same voltage level. You can just connect them up with the ground and don't need to worry any further.

In practice there can be slight differences every now and then buth those don't really apply here.